# Can I use textblob to predict a likert scale outcome?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, textblob

I have about 300 participants who generated 45 short situations each (though many participants wrote the same situation) and rated the degree that they would feel anxious in that situation (1-5 likert scale).

Sample data:

```
train = [('being at a sports game', '1'), ('selecting group members for a group project', '2'), ('interacting with overly dressed people', '1'), ('partnering up with a stranger for a class', '3'), ('having your presentation criticized by an audience member', '4'), ('being in a situation you cannot control', '3')]
```

I was wondering if I might be able to use textblob in python to determine if there are any common words that would lead to someone scoring higher on this single item likert scale.

What I have so far is the simple category classification system.

```
#Import libraries
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier

#Train the NBC with training data
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)

#Examine Training Accuracy
cl.accuracy(train)

#Generates a list of informative features
cl.show_informative_features(50)
```

1. How could I get this to take into account that this is interval (or some would say ordinal) data rather than nominal? (e.g., the inclusion of the word "stranger" leads to an X% increase in anxiety.)
2. If this is impossible (or even if it isn't), is there any way to print the percent probability of a given situation being labeled in each likert category? (e.g., 1 = 0.08; 2 = 0.23, 3 = 0.44, 4 = 0.19, 5 = 0.06)

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: `100 / 20 = 5.0` , `1.0 / 20 * 100 = 5.0`, `0.2 / 20 * 100  = 1.0`, `0.3 / 20 * 100 = 1.5`, 0.4 / 20 * 100 = 2.0`

Comment: From your description, I would say your data are ordinal, not interval.

Comment: @alvas Thank you for your comment. Though, I am not exactly sure what you are trying to tell me. Is there a simple scalar that can be used to solve one of my two questions?

Comment: @BrenBarn Thank you for the comment. Whether Likert scales are interval or ordinal seems to be of some debate at least in my field (Psychology), so I edited the OP in order to reflect this.